# Web page displays and animated times table

Tags: javascript, html

Hi everyone I am currently stuck trying to debug my program. MY goal is for whenever the button "Start Animation" is clicked, the web page displays an animated times table according to the number that the user enters in the text field in the following manner. For example, if the user entered the number 6 in the text field, then the animation displays 1 x 6 = 6, one second later it replaces it with 2 x 6 = 12, one second later it replaces it with 3 x 6 = 18, etc. If it is 9 x 6 = 54, then one second later it becomes 1 x 6 = 6, and then 2 x 6 = 12, and so on.

```js
var counter;
var animationOn = false;
var counterAnimation;

function updateAnimation() {

  var value = document.getElementById('value1').value;

  for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
      var product = j * value;
      var counterSpan = document.getElementById("counterHolder");
      counterSpan.innerHTML = product;
    }
  }
  counterAnimation = setTimeout(updateAnimation, 1000);

}

function startAnimation() {
  if (animationOn == false) {
    animationOn = true;
    counter = 1;
    counterAnimation = setTimeout(updateAnimation, 1000);
  }
}

function stopAnimation() {
  if (animationOn == true) {
    animationOn = false;
    clearTimeout(updateAnimation);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="startAnimation();">
        Start animation 
    </button>
  <button onclick="stopAnimation();">
        Stop animation
    </button><br><br>
  <label>Enter an integer: </label>
  <input type="number" size=20 id=value1 name="value">
  <span id="counterHolder">0</span>
</body>
```

Comment: (1) Start with small number. 10000000 not realistic and browser freezing. (2) 
Your HTML structure is broken. you have 2 `</body>` and input is out of body. (3) use input type number

Comment: Thank you for the help i have implemented these solutions into the document but the animation doesn't display a new equation each second it only skips straight to the final equation and i can figure out why?

Comment: @4EACH (4) Stop using `var` use `let` instead, if you will be changing your variable or `const` for the constant variable. (5) What is a problem with your code? It doesn't work at all or maybe it makes something different from what you have been expecting?

Comment: @Davyd Veremchuk It does something different from what I'm expecting. For example, if I input 6 it should display 6 then 12 all the way to 54 then reset back down to 6 again and keep repeating until I stop the animation.

Comment: Keep it simple. you know the start point, end point and the current number.  Why are you using many loops? calculate next every 1sec if current < end.

Answer (score 0):

## Edited

Here is a complete solution which makes changes displayed value by time

```js
let counter;
let animationOn = false;
let counterAnimation;
let mult = 1;
        
function updateAnimation() {
  let value = document.getElementById('value1').value;
  let counterSpan = document.getElementById("counterHolder");
  if (mult >= 10) {
    mult = 1;
    counter = null;
    animationOn = false;
    counterAnimation = null;
    counterSpan.innerHTML = 0;
    return;
  }

  let product = mult * value; 
  counterSpan.innerHTML = product;
  mult++
   counterAnimation = setTimeout(updateAnimation, 1000)
}

function startAnimation() {
  if (!animationOn) 
  {
    animationOn = true;
    counter = 1;
    counterAnimation = setTimeout(updateAnimation, 1000);
  }
}

function stopAnimation() {
  if (animationOn) 
  {
    animationOn = false;
    clearTimeout(counterAnimation);
    mult = 1
    counter = null
    animationOn = false
    counterAnimation = null
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="startAnimation();">
        Start animation 
    </button>
  <button onclick="stopAnimation();">
        Stop animation
    </button><br><br>
  <label>Enter an integer: </label>
  <input type="number" size=20 id=value1 name="value">
  <span id="counterHolder">0</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Davyd worked a charm but how would i make it reset back to the original starting count once it reaches the max value

Comment: @Jake I updated my answer so now it will reset the value to 0, one second later after the last 9 * n was shown.
P.S:
If my answer helped you, I would be glad if you could vote it up :)